# Extract text from a string knowing the previous part of the string (Python)

Tags: python

I have a list of strings set like this:

`< Some text.... "The name is": "123456789", "The other useful thing is": "456789412", Some other text... >`

I need code to find `"The name is"`  in the string and extract `"123456789"` and read `"The other useful thing is"` and extract `"456789412"`

In all the string the format (first part) is the same but the part I want to extract changes.

Thanks for help

Comment: What have you done so far? Any ideas?

Comment: Is your "list" actually a dict?

Comment: Can you give valid Python code that creates the strings?  It’s not clear if you have one string or a list or a dict of strings.  The angle brackets aren’t valid Python.

Comment: You say this is a _list of strings_. _Where_ exactly are these strings stored - in a big string, a dictionary, set, tuple or a list?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.